# SAP UI 5 Search clear button

Tags: search, sapui5

When I click on Clear search(cross) it take 30 sec to clear search text why it work slowly.
Please help me to resolve problem.

```
<SearchField id="idSoldSearch"  search="onSoldSearch" width="100%" />
```

here I bind data through web service at  onSoldSearch function.

Comment: Can you show us the controller code, please?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the cross button of Search, it will also trigger the event handler of onSoldSearch, then it will trigger a web service call with the search value empty. It will take 30 sec to make a round trip .You can open the Chrome F12 developer tool to monitor the Network call time.

If you really want to make the WebService call when the search value is empty, You can show a busy dialog.

```
onSoldSearch:function(oEvent) {
    var sQuery = oEvent.getParameters().query;

    //adjust following code based on your real code

    var onSuccess = function(oResponse) {
        //some logic
        this.hideBusyDialog();
    }

    var onError = function(oResponse) {

        //some logic
        this.hideBusyDialog();
    }

    webService.call("YourWebServiceurl?"+query,onSuccess,onError);    

    this.showBusyDialog();

}
```

Please see the example about [BusyDialog](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.BusyDialogLight/preview).

Comment: can you explain how can I add validation ? or show a busy dialog Thanks, Mit